# How to install 32bit Microsoft Online Services Module for Windows PowerShell on 64bit workstation?

Tags: wcf, office365

I have Microsoft Online Services Module of 64-bit version for Windows PowerShell installed and working correctly.

I ran into problems when using Visual Web Developer Express 2010 to create WCF web service(32bit), which uses those cmdlets. Exception just tells me that

```
The term 'Import-Module MSOnline' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.
```

Default installer does not permit installation of 32bit version.

Comment: You need to either make service 64-bit or use the 32-bit module.  Its not possible to use the 32-bit module within a 64-bit process.

Comment: I've tried to import C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\System.Management.Automation.dll as Reference, but that did not help.